# SQL SERVER MIRRORING

Tags: sql-server

I need your advice whether to use the SQL Server database mirroring for the below issue.

My company has 3 branches inside the city namely branches A, B and C. The main server is setup in Branch A. And all the users from Branches A, B and C access this main server. Branch B and C are connected to main server via VPN. This means that if VPN fails, then Branch B and Branch C users cannot access the main server.

Now my questions are:

1. Can I use this mirroring concept by setting up new servers in Branch B and Branch C?
2. If yes, then lets say that all users from A, B and C are accessing the main server from A. during VPN failure, will the users from B and C would be automatically connected to their local servers at B and C? And after the connection establishes, will the data be replicated to the main server at A?
3. If no, then what best option can I use to allow the users of A, B and C can work without interruption even if the VPN fails.

I kindly request your advise or solution regarding the above query.

Answer (score 1):

> can i use this mirroring concept by setting up new servers in Branch B and 
>   Branch C?

No. Mirroring and AOAG assume one of the nodes is active, the others are at best read only (with AOAG).

Replication would work, but it would require reprogramming FOR replication.

> If no, then what best option can i use to allow the users of A, B and C can 
>   work without interruption even if the VPN fails.

There is none. You could move the db to a place which fails more rarely (data center). Otherwise you really need to go into replication, but that in most cases requires some special programming approach, especially if data is shared (i.e. one data item can be edited in multiple places).

Comment: TomTom, thank you so much for your response. I appreciate it. Could you please suggest whether the "Sql Transactional Replication" concept be helpful to overcome this issue?